# -E parameter exclude the string from result

Tags: regex, bash

We are trying to create regex for the following string:-

```
$last_id . ' where ticket_id=' . $this->getId()  {
```

to test our regex we wrote the following bash one line:-

```
echo "  $last_id . ' where ticket_id=' . $this->getId()  {"| grep -i -E  ".*(:?.*\$*.WHERE.*) " --color=auto;
```

The result is:-

```
. ' where ticket_id=' . ->getId()  {
```

expected result:-

```
. ' where ticket_id=' . $this->getId()  {
```

But the -E parameter excludes `$this`. Please help we are stuck.

Comment: It does not seem related to the POSIX flavor. Your regex is wrong. Try [`grep -ioE  "\.\s*'\s*WHERE.*)" --color=auto;`](https://ideone.com/GpQ00N).

Comment: Any feedback? Am I right you just need to get the matched value starting with a `.`, 0+ whitespaces, `'`, 0+ whitespaces, `WHERE`, and then the rest of the line?

Comment: What are the requirements, Aayush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$this` gets dropped out before reaching `grep`, because it's being expanded by shell as a variable named `this`.

See:

```
$ echo "  $last_id . ' where ticket_id=' . $this->getId()  {"
   . ' where ticket_id=' . ->getId()  {
```

To prevent parameter expansion in shell, just escape the `$`:

```
echo "  \$last_id . ' where ticket_id=' . \$this->getId()  {"
  $last_id . ' where ticket_id=' . $this->getId()  {
```